# Angular5 - Filtering the array of objects

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, filter

I am trying to filter view of products but I don't know why original array is being modified, resulting in not correct filtering...

*categories* is an array with objects of categories {title, products[]}

*categoriesView* I want it to be a  filtered array

```
filterByKeyword(keyword: string) {
    let k = keyword.toLowerCase();

    this.categoriesView = this.categories.filter((c) => {
      for(let q = 0; q < c.products.length; q++) {
        return c.products[q].title.toLowerCase().indexOf(k) >= 0;
      }
    });

    // filter products of each category:
    for(let q = 0; q < this.categoriesView.length; q++) {
      for(let z = 0; z < this.categories.length; z++) {
        if(this.categoriesView[q].title == this.categories[z].title){
          this.categoriesView[q].products = this.categories[z].products.filter((p) => {
              return p.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(k) >= 0;
          });
        }
      }
    }

    console.log("Categories View: ", this.categoriesView);
    console.log("Categories: ", this.categories);
}
```

First filter with categories works correctly. When I dive into products problems appear and original array is modified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work:

```
filterByKeyword(keyword: string) {
    const k = keyword.toLowerCase();
    this.categoriesView = this.categories.map(x => Object.assign({}, x));
    this.categoriesView = this.categoriesView.filter((category) => {
        category.products = category.products.filter(
          (product)=> product.title.toLowerCase().includes(k));

        return category.products.length>0 }
      );
    if(this.categoriesView.length===0){
      this.categoriesView = this.categories.map(x => Object.assign({}, x));
    }
  }
```

Comment: Perfect! Works like charm :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Sorry but I had to step in.

Your filtering and code are horrible.

Here it is, rewritten, clearer, simpler, and it might even should work :

```
filterByKeyword(keyword: string) {

    const k = keyword.toLowerCase();

    this.categoriesView = this.categories.filter(c => {
      let ret = false;
      for(let q of c.products) {
        if(q.title.toLowerCase().includes(k)) { ret = true; }
      }
      return ret;
    });

    // Even cleaner
    // this.categoriesView = this.categories.filter(c => c.products.find(p => p.title.toLowerCase().includes(k)));

    for (const view of this.categoriesView) {
      for (const cat of this.categories) {
        if (view.title === cat.title) {
          view.products = cat.products.filter(p => p.title.toLowerCase().includes(k));
        }
      }
    }

    console.log("Categories View: ", this.categoriesView);
    console.log("Categories: ", this.categories);
}
```

Comment: Hey thank you! It's the result of finding proper solution over hours... It works nice, however after filtering once, original array has only 1 product instead of many.

Comment: Well this doesn't come from this piece of code, since nowhere you wrote somethign along the lines of `this.categories = ...`. Are you sure the problem isn't coming from elsewhere ?

Comment: @trichetriche categories is an array of category objects { title, products: [ {...} ]. After fetching data from firestore this is the only operation that takes place.

Comment: And once fetched, is there more than one object in it ?

Comment: @trichetriche, yes

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not saying you're lying, but I find it hard to believe : could you paste your two console logs just under the declaration of your variable "k", and compare them ?

Comment: @trichetriche I input string which matches 2 products, displays 2 products with its category, I delete the input, instead of 3 only those 2 are on screen.

Comment: Well, the issue has changed already ! New question : how do you call this function `filterByKeyword` ?

Comment: @trichetriche <input #search (keyup)="filterByKeyword(search.value)" />

Comment: Before declaring k, add this : `if (!keyword) { this.categoriesView = this.categories; return; }`, and I highly recommend you to use a pipe for this kind of things.

Comment: @trichetriche I already tried, but it makes no sense since after first filter both categoriesView and categories change - lose filtered data. Problem must be related with references while filtering the categories.

Comment: Could you please try the exact code I gave you ? And there's no reference issue : filter, find, reduce and almost every array functions return new objects (well, arrays). If you say you don't get your 3 items back, then it's either because your return key isn't working, or because the query is empty and can't be found. So unless you're deleting your input by using the mouse this is the only option left ...

Comment: But again, putting logs would help greatly, but people tend to not do things we ask on this site ;)

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, objects are passed by reference. So
`categoriesView` actually IS a reference to your `categories` array and changing the properties in one will change both.
If you want to create a separate object, you can use `angular.copy()`

```
this.categoriesView = angular.copy(this.categories.filter((c) => {
  for(let q = 0; q < c.products.length; q++) {
    return c.products[q].title.toLowerCase().indexOf(k) >= 0;
  }
}););
```

see more info [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy)

Comment: Is there any replacement for AngularJS copy method in Angular2?

Comment: Use array destructuring to create a copy: `newArray = [...oldArray];`. BTW, angular.copy() is only for AngularJS (1.X) and not for Angular (2+)

Comment: @merlosy destructuring did not help

Answer (score 0):

there is an issue with :

```
this.categories.filter( (c) => {...} )
```

Your array is not iterated properly as it returns at the first round. You should concider using a temporary boolean as a buffer for your loop, then return it.

Also, concider refactor your code with [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), it will make your code a lot more readable

```
this.categoriesView = this.categories.filter(c => {
    return c.products.reduce( (acc, product) => {
        return acc || product.title.toLowerCase().includes(k);
    }, false);
});
```

Comment: As I said in the rejection of your edit on my post, reduce isn't a function a beginner can use. If you really want to make your code cleaner and more readable, consider using `find` instead, and rely on truthy/falsy values.

Comment: the concept of reduce is quite straightforward when you look at the docs..  btw I always concider myself a beginner

Comment: And the concept of filtering an array is pretty straightforward without reading any doc, yet he spent several hours on it. I'm not saying you're wrong, I agree with you : you just can't advise advise it to someone who is already struggling.